# Issue with RxVirtualScrollViewport: Position of Data Changes on Navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

**Problem Description:**
I'm encountering an issue with the rx-virtual-scroll-viewport package in my Angular application. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
<div rxVirtualScrollElement style="min-height: 100%">
    <!-- Content Before -->
    <div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid red; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;" class="mr-x">
        Content Before Content Before Content Before
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;" class="mr-x">
        <rx-virtual-scroll-viewport (scrolledIndexChange)="rxaScrolledIndex$.next($event)" autosize
            [resizeObserverConfig]="{  extractSize: extractSize }" [runwayItemsOpposite]="runwayItemsOpposite"
            [runwayItems]="runwayItems" class="viewport">
            <div class="item" *rxVirtualFor="let item of data$; let index$ = index$; let i = index;
                trackBy: trackItem; renderCallback: rendered; strategy: $any(strategy$)"
                class="item" (click)="GoToDetails(item,index$,i);">
                <div class="content">
                    <p style="font-weight: 700;"><span>{{ i}}. </span><span>{{ item.title }}</span></p>
                    <p>{{item.info}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </rx-virtual-scroll-viewport>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Details:**

- I have a list of data(item), upon clicking on an item from the list, the application navigates to a detail page.
- When returning to the list page, the position of the data within the rx-virtual-scroll-viewport changes.
- Similarly, navigating between (two) tabs leads to the same issue of data position changing.

**Requested Assistance:**
I'm seeking guidance on how to maintain the position of the data within the rx-virtual-scroll-viewport when navigating between pages or tabs. Any suggestions or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.